# No Audio in Firefox

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio

Videos in Firefox version 62 have no audio. I have read that pulseaudio must be running and I tried this command

```
$ sudo pulseaudio --start --exit-idle-time=-1
```

per Firefox support page and restarted FF, but there is still no audio.  The output from that command is

```
$ pulseaudio --start --exit-idle-time=-1
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at {32eef4ee022648c6ba11ec360b709b37}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native, which appears to be local. Probing deeper.
```

Sooooo, I can't find any other suggestions online as that is supposed to fix it.  Suggestions?

I have also tried to install pulseaudio just to see what info would come back.  Here it is

```
$ sudo apt install pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pulseaudio is already the newest version (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1).
```

P.S. : Chrome plays audio just fine

Comment: Yes Firefox requires PulseAudio

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.  I needed to install pavucontrol and change the output.  For some reason it was defaulted to HDMI even though I did not have anything connected to HDMI.