# No sound Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, sound, hdmi

Sound was working fine before I connected the HDMI one day. Audio works when HDMI cable plugged in, through monitor, laptop or earphones. It does not when disconnected. It only works in VLC when I change the audio device from HDMI to Built in Audio.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try ubuntu 19.04 :) ! does this solution help : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131006/no-sound-on-18-04#1131006 ?

Comment: @tatsu thanks for the help. This is what really solved my problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083522/no-audio-in-firefox